# How to use OIDC with AWS Amplify in Bitbucket Pipeline?

Tags: continuous-integration, openid-connect, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines, aws-amplify-cli

I'd like to run tests on my React app first and after they were successful, I'd like to create an Amplify app that gets manually deployed within the pipe.

My current pipeline is failing and looks like this:

```html
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        name: Build and Deploy
        image: node:18
        oidc: true
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          - export AWS_ROLE_ARN=arn:aws:iam::816202482289:role/BitbucketPipelines
          - export AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE=$(pwd)/web-identity-token
          - echo $BITBUCKET_STEP_OIDC_TOKEN > $(pwd)/web-identity-token
          - npm install
          - npm install -g @aws-amplify/cli
          - npm run build
          - node setup_amplify_script.js
```

The error I receive:
 Error in the command line parameter for awscloudformation configuration.
project level config set useProfile to false, but access key or region is missing.

Answer (score 0):

OIDC is not available, so you have to pass the access keys.